# Show that the range $R(T)$ is not closed in $l^2$ norm for $T:(x_1, . . . , x_n, . . .) → (x_1, . . . ,\frac{1}{n}x_n, . . .)$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, open-map

**Here is the question and the answer:**

[image]

---

I would like to ask in the first and second line, how does $R(T)$ being closed in $l^2$ and the open mapping theorem imply the inverse mapping $S$ being bounded.

Comment: Since $T:\ell^2\rightarrow R(T)$ is open by the open mapping theorem, its inverse is continuous by definition of continuity (inverse images of open sets open) and thus bounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closed subspace of a Banach space is Banach. You can think of $T$ as  a linear continuous bijection from $\ell^{2}$ onto $R(T)$ and open Mapping Theorem can be applied bacause  $\ell^{2}$ and  $R(T)$ are Banach spaces.

Comment: I see. But we already know that $l^2$ is Banach and $T$ is a surjection hence $R(T)$=$l^2$. It seems like $R(T)$ could be a Banach space without the condition of being closed.
Doing the same approach again to show $R(T)$ is closed seems also work.

Comment: @mathnoob $T$ is not a surjection. The sequence $(1,\frac 1 2  , \frac   1 3, ...)$ cannot be $Tx$ for any $x$: if it is $Tx$ then $\frac {x_n} n=\frac 1 n$ so $x_n=1$ for all $n$. But then $\sum |x_n|^{2}=\infty$.

Comment: $T:\ell^2\rightarrow R(T)$ with this image is a surjection and if $R(T)$ was closed this would be a bijection between Banach spaces and then the open mapping theorem would imply that it is open and thus the inverse bounded which it is not, so $R(T)$ cannot be closed

Comment: @ geetha290krm Oh, I get it. So this is the point of introducing $R(T)$ to replace $l^2$ in order to get a surjection. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Peter Melech Yes, I see what did I missed now. Thank you.

Comment: I do not see a reason for applying such a strong tool as open mapping theorem. The range is a proper dense subspace of $\ell^2,$ hence it is not closed.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I agree. But I thought OP had a specific question about the presented proof.

Answer (score 2):

The range of the operator $T$ is dense as $e_n=T(ne_n).$ But the range is not equal $\ell^2$ as $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty\notin T(\ell^2)$, (as observed by @gettha290krm) Indeed if $(Tx)_n={1/ n},$ then $x_n=1$ for any $n.$

Comment: May I ask how to show the range of $T$ is dense as well? By $e_n$=$T(ne_n)$, I know $e_n$$\in$$R(T)$ and I wonder how to prove $\forall$ x$\in$$l^2$, $\|x-e_n\|$<$\epsilon$ $\forall$ $\epsilon$>0.

Comment: The range of $T$ contains all elements $e_n.$ Hence it contains all finite linear combinations of $e_n,$ i.e. the elements of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n a_ke_k.$ Given $x\in \ell^1.$ Then $x^{(n)}:=\sum_{k=1}^nx_ke_k$ belongs to the range of $T$ and  $\|x-x^{(n)}\|=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |x_k| \to 0$ when $n\to \infty.$

Comment: I think I got some of the ideas. We are considering $l^1$ since it is greater than $l^2$. And $l^1$ is a subset of c_0, so $x_k$ → 0 as k→∞. Intuitively, it implies $\sum_{k=n+1} ^{\infty} |x_k|$→0 as n→∞ but I couldn't prove it rigorously. Would you give me more hints please?

Comment: @mathnoob Sorry. I have mixed up the norms in my previous comment. It should be $\|x-x^{(n)}\|^2=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |x_k|^2\to 0$ when $n\to \infty.$

Comment: Thanks, I see now. This proof is simpler indeed.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, do we know the codimension of $T$? Is it just one? i.e., $\textrm{Ran}(T)\oplus \{\{1/n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\} = l_2$ as vector space?

Comment: The codimension is infinite as  the sequences $v_a:=\{n^{-a}\}$ do not belong to the range for $1<a\le {3/2}$ and the elements $\{v_a\}$ for different $a$  and $R(T)$ are linearly independent.